# Why does my multi-index dataframe have duplicate values for indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-level

I have the following pd.DataFrame called df:

```
                   date     cluster_label        value
0   2018-11-14 02:16:22                 0          1.5
1   2018-11-14 02:16:22                 0          7.0
2   2018-11-14 02:16:22                 0          2.5
3   2018-11-14 02:16:22                 1          3.0
4   2018-11-14 02:16:22                 1          0.5
5   2018-11-14 02:16:22                 2          1.0
```

I do the following command to convert the date column to only have month and year values, before setting the multi level index or the dataframe:

```
self.df['date'] = self.df['date'].dt.to_period('M')
self.df.set_index(['cluster_label', 'date'], inplace=True)
```

Now, the output is like so:

```
                           value
cluster_label date                                                                  
0              2018-11     1.5
               2018-11     7.0
               2018-11     2.5
1              2018-11     3.0
               2018-11     0.5
2              2018-11     1.0
```

But this is wrong. I want the output to not have duplicate indices for the date column. The output should look like:

```
                           value
cluster_label date                                                                  
0              2018-11     1.5
                           7.0
                           2.5
1              2018-11     3.0
                           0.5
2              2018-11     1.0
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I change my code to get this desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to append a `cumcount`ed level:

```
df.set_index(df.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount(), append=True)

                         value
cluster_label date            
0             2018-11 0    1.5
                      1    7.0
                      2    2.5
1             2018-11 0    3.0
                      1    0.5
2             2018-11 0    1.0
```

Where,

```
df.set_index(df.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount(), append=True).index 
# MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2], [2018-11], [0, 1, 2]],
#            labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0]],
#            names=['cluster_label', 'date', None])
```

---

Another option (I don't recommend is) is to mask those values explicitly and reset the index.

```
u = np.where(df.index.duplicated(), '', df.index.get_level_values(1))
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.get_level_values(0), u])

df
                       value
cluster_label               
0             2018-11    1.5
                         7.0
                         2.5
1             2018-11    3.0
                         0.5
2             2018-11    1.0
```