# Grouping without losing original information using `df.groupby()`

Tags: pandas

Not sure that is feasible, but I'm trying to achieve the following with `df.groupby()`: let's say we have the following dataframe

```
name   target
A         1
A         2
A        0.5
B         3
B         1
B         2
C        0.6
C        1.2
```

and I want to group it based on `name` without losing the original information on `target`. My expected output would be something like:

```
name   target  count
A         1      3
          2
         0.5
B         3      3
          1
          2
C        0.6     2
         1.2
```

Comment: You want `df['count'] = df.groupby('name').transform('count')`?

Comment: sort of, but possibly without having to repeat then the same `name` for different targets, to enhance readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multi index

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['count'] = df.groupby('name').transform('count')
df = df.set_index(['name', 'count', 'target'])
df.head()
```

**Update**:
As previous code will result in an empty dataframe, you can do the following:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('name').transform('count')
df = df.set_index(['name', 'count'])
df.set_index(df.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount(), append=True).head()
```

Code is taken from [Why does my multi-index dataframe have duplicate values for indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299267/why-does-my-multi-index-dataframe-have-duplicate-values-for-indices)

Comment: mmmh I've tried but then everything gets into the index that way and the dataframe becomes empty..

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it's only to enhance readability of data, not processing it.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent `name` entries being repeated for all different targets? Somehow as displayed in my expected output.

Comment: still not working in my case...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset the values of `'name'` to empty when `grouping` and write only on the first row, and for `'count'` immediately create a column with empty rows and write the value in the `first row`.

Just keep in mind these are not multi-indexes. If where there are no values, these will be empty strings.

```
import pandas as pd

df['count'] = ''


def f(x):
    df.loc[x.index[0], 'count'] = x['name'].count()
    aaa = df.loc[x.index[0], 'name']
    df.loc[x.index, 'name'] = ''
    df.loc[x.index[0], 'name'] = aaa



df.groupby('name').apply(f)

print(df)
```

Output

```
  name  target count
0    A     1.0     3
1          2.0      
2          0.5      
3    B     3.0     3
4          1.0      
5          2.0      
6    C     0.6     2
7          1.2
```